# Update/Put method based on custom id?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

The below is the standard scafolding code for a PUT method in a Web Api 2 project with Entity Framework.

This works well, when you have the id of the product.

But, I have a situation, where I want to update/put a product based on not the unique id in the table, but a different field 'internalRef' (string) combined with a manufacture id.
So, I first wish to check if there is a product with internalRef='123' and manufactureId=1. If not return NotFound(). If there is, then update that product with the data posted.

Any sugstions as to how to do this?

```
[Route("product/update")]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutProduct(int id, Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != product.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProductExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question, can you not that change the Put method signature?!

Comment: I suspect i surtenly can. But how? I feel like i have stared myself blind, to see the obvious

Comment: Something like this: public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutProduct(string id, Product product) no?

Answer (score 0):

The Put example is just a template that you have to modify depending on your requirements. In your case what makes your entity unique is not an Id but an internalRef and a manufacturer. So you only have to replace/adapt your code to work with this composite unique id of internalRef+manufacturer.

```
[Route("product/update")]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutProduct(string internalRef, int manufacturer, Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (internalRef != product.InternalRef && manufacturer != product.Manufacturer)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProductExists(internalRef, manufacturer))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Remember to change the method `ProductExists(int id)` by your own `ProductExists(string internalRef, int manufacturer)` to work properly.

Comment: Ahh, looks like something i can use. but i am unsure of what this does; internalRef != product.InterRef. What is it checking for? And the ModelStat.IsValid, wont be false, when tehre is no int id, submitted?

Comment: 'internalRef != product.InternalRef && manufacturer != product.Manufacturer' checks that the internalRef and manufacturer are from the product that you are going to change. If not, you would be changing an incorrect product. The same logic is applied to the 'id != product.Id in your code'. By the other way, ModelState.IsValid will validate the Product instance sent by parameter, not the id. Check the next link to understand it better: http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/.

Comment: I tried your suggstion now, and i m getting the error "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)". I then figured out that it works when I include the unique "id" property in the PUT. But this is excatly what i wanted to avoid, as the one updating the record, does not know the ID, but only the internalRef and manufactureId? Am i missing something? :)